# How can I add "disabled" attribute to text field based on dropdown selection in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm tring to have a field in each row only necessary if specific dropdown in that row is selected. So if value 1 is selected then it is disabled.

Here's what I have:

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Selecter').change(function () {
            var $this = $(this); 
            var $row = $this.closest("tr").find('.accountNumber');
            if (this.value == "1") {
                $('#row').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select id="Select1" class="Selecter">
<option value="">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>

</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" class="accountNumber"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select id="select2" class="Selecter">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>

</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" class="accountNumber" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8efeyhc5/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vLx658of/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Selecter').change(function () {
            var $this = $(this); 
            console.log($this.val())
            var $row = $this.closest("tr").find('.accountNumber');
            if ($this.val() == "1") { // use $this.val()
                $row.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // use $row here because you want to disable selected row field
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use `$row` while applying `.attr` method as there is no `$('#row')` element in `DOM`
- Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`
- If condition could be eliminated by `$row.prop("disabled", this.value == "1");`
- Use `.change()` to invoke the handler initially.

---

```
$('.Selecter').change(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find('.accountNumber').prop("disabled", this.value == "1");
}).change();
```

```js
$('.Selecter').change(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find('.accountNumber').prop("disabled", this.value == "1");
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="Select1" class="Selecter">
        <option value="">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="accountNumber" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="select2" class="Selecter">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="accountNumber" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8efeyhc5/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
$('.Selecter').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val == 1) {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".accountNumber").prop("disabled", true);

  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("accountNumber").prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8efeyhc5/4/)

Problem with your code is, you are taking the current row's account number to a variable called `$row`, But in the next line you just using the selector '#row' which dont have any relation with the previous line.